# Sum of series $1−ω^2+ω^4−ω^6+ω^8−ω^{10}+ω^{12}+⋯+ω^{600}−ω^{602}+ω^{604}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I need to find sum of the series involving cube roots of unity $1−ω^2+ω^4−ω^6+ω^8−ω^{10}+ω^{12}+⋯+ω^{600}−ω^{602}+ω^{604}$.

Found it in an old test paper.

I applied Geometric Progression Sum Formula.

$$\frac{1.((-ω^2)^{(303+1)}-1)}{-ω^2-1}$$

$$=\frac{(ω^{608}-1)}{-ω^2-1}$$

$$=\frac{(ω^{2}-1)}{-ω^2-1}$$

$$=\frac{(ω^{2}-1)}{ω}$$

$$=(ω-ω^2)$$

$$=(-1-2ω^2)$$

But the answer given is $-2ω^2$ only.Don't know how.Can anyone spot any mistake in what I did?

P.S:Thanks guys.I found my mistake now.Applied the formula wrong in the first step.It should be

$$\frac{1.((-ω^2)^{(302+1)}-1)}{-ω^2-1}$$

Comment: In your first line the $303+1$ should be $302+1$

Comment: Oh I applied the formula wrong.Thanks @RossMillikan.Silly me :-P...had got out of touch with it :-P!

Comment: Another approach is to note that the sum of six successive terms is zero, so we can delete the last $300$ terms and be left with $1-\omega^2+\omega^4=1+\omega-\omega^2=-2\omega^2$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{r=0}^{302}(-\omega^2)^r=1\cdot\dfrac{1-(-\omega^2)^{303}}{1-(-\omega^2)}=\dfrac{1+(\omega^3)^{202}}{1+\omega^2}=?  $$

Comment: Oh I applied the formula wrong for GP summation.Silly me.Had got out of touch with it.Thanks for the quick answer!